# experience with AWS cloudHSM and remote-signer

Tags: baker, remote-signer

I'm wondering how to generate keys on cloudHSM and setup the remote signer to use with the baker

thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you looked at this https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/pricing/ ? It's roughly $1,110 USD per month to use AWS cloudHSM.